# iOS UIImageView Memory Problem

Tags: iphone, memory, sdk, uiimageview

I've been trying to solve a problem to do with the image in my UIImageView being released due to memory warnings.

Here's my situation:

1) I declare a UIImageView in my .H:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *fightStyleImage;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *fightStyleImage;
```

2) I synthesize and dealloc in my .M:

```
@synthesize fightStyleImage;
...
...
-(void)dealloc{
[fightStyleImage release];
...
}
```

3) I attach the fightStyleImage to a UIImageView in Interface Builder.

4) Part of my app's experience allows a user to swipe on the device, to cycle through 5 different images. I am using the following code to achieve that:

```
// Load next image
UIImage *theImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fighter1.png"];
fightStyleImage.image = theImg;
```

Everything works really well, and I'm happy with the performance, experience, etc.

However, when I pop to another view controller (or to an MFMailComposeViewController, or an Address Book picker) and my device receives a memory warning (either through the simulator, or on the device), the following happens when I return to my original view controller: the iOS seems to jettison my UIImageView image (I assume because it is the most expensive object in memory), and I am left with a black screen (i.e. no image). If I begin to swipe again, the images return and continue to cycle properly.

I'd love to hear any thoughts on this, and thanks in advance for any solutions/insights anyone might have. In particular, I'm interested (of course!) in restoring my image that has been jettisoned from memory.

-SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly implement the `viewDidLoad` and the `viewDidUnload` to setup and release your views. Read the iOS section of the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2) for assistance. I also recommend you move your IBOutlet declaration from the ivar to the property as so

```
UIImageView *fightStyleImage;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *fightStyleImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I moved my IBOutlet declaration to the property, as you suggested, and read the MMPG link that you provided. I added self.fightStyleImage = nil to my viewDidUnload method, but am not sure how to implement in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: When loaded from the nib the property will already be properly set so you do not really need to do anything except for additional customization.

Comment: Joe - in your original answer you mentioned implementing viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload to setup/release [my] views. When you say 'setup/release your views', can you be specific about which objects, exactly? Thanks.

Comment: When `viewDidLoad` is called all of your `IBOutlet`s are already connected. If there is anything custom you need to add to your view or if there are customizations you need to do to your view that you were not able to do in Interface Builder then that is the place. Otherwise you wont need to implement `viewDidLoad` and just set all of your `IBOutlet`s to nil in `viewDidUnload`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe due to using **`imageNamed:`** method as it caches the images into your memory and will be forced to free only when Low Memory warning occurs. Better go this way:

```
UIImage *image=[[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]autorelease];
```